Laravel 11 not executing Policy
So I have a Model, Middleware and a Policy.
The problem is that I seem to can not get the policy to work correctly.
This is my policy code:
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\ApiKey;

class ApiKeyPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given API key is valid for the given user.
     *
     * @param  string  $apiUser
     * @param  string  $apiKey
     * @return bool
     */
    public function access($apiUser, $apiKey)
    {
        Log::info("Checking API key for user: $apiUser with key: $apiKey");

        $userApiKey = ApiKey::where('key_user', $apiUser)->first();

        if (!$userApiKey) {
            Log::warning("User not found: $apiUser");
            return false;
        }

        $valid = $userApiKey->key === $apiKey;

        Log::info("API key valid: " . ($valid ? 'Yes' : 'No'));

        return $valid;
    }
}

This is my middleware code:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class VerifyApiKeyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $apiKey = $request->header('X-AW-KEY');
        $apiUser = $request->header('X-AW-USER');

        Log::info("Received API User: $apiUser, API Key: $apiKey");

        if (!$apiKey || !$apiUser) {
            Log::warning('API key or user not found');
            abort(401, 'API key or user not found');
        }

        // This is always false somehow
        $allowed = Gate::allows('access-api', [$apiUser, $apiKey]);

        Log::info("Gate check result for API User: $apiUser, API Key: $apiKey, Allowed: " . ($allowed ? 'Yes' : 'No'));

        if (!$allowed) {
            Log::warning('Unauthorized API key');
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized API key');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

Inside the AppServiceProvider.php inside the boot() function I am registering the Policy the following way: Gate::define('access-api', [ApiKeyPolicy::class, 'access']);
This is how I use it:
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\LoginController;

use App\Http\Middleware\VerifyApiKeyMiddleware;

Route
    ::prefix('/user')
    ->middleware(['api', VerifyApiKeyMiddleware::class])
    ->group(function ()
    {
        Route::post('/authenticate', [LoginController::class, 'DoAuth'])->name('api.user.authenticate');
    }
);

My problem is that despite having all the logs and such it never actually does execute the Policy code therefore always returning a false. I really do not see where I did go wrong in this. I tried to map the policies inside the AppServiceProvider but this also did not help.

What error you are getting ?

@Subha That is the problem.. the Policy does not get executed at all. I am not getting any single log that I have defined inside the Policy.

The policy assumes the 1st parameter will be the Authenticated user so you will need a signature of e.g. public function access(?User $authUser, $apiUser, $apiKey) but I think you need to rethink this approach in general because if you are using the api user headers to determine who the user is maybe you need to use a custom guard and/or user provider

Ohhh..... okay, well when adding the ?User $authUser it works now. Yes, I actually wanted to do a custom guard for that before but I thought that a Gate also is enough eventually. Will look into the Guard ! Thanks alot!

Thanks to @apokryfos for pointing me in the right direction.
I now decided to remove the whole policy and gate thing and added an Auth::viaRequest() to my AppServiceProvider boot().
    Auth::viaRequest('api-token', function (Request $request) {
        $apiUser = $request->header('X-AW-USER');
        $apiKey = $request->header('X-AW-KEY');

        Log::info("Checking API key for user: $apiUser with key: $apiKey");

        if (!$apiUser || !$apiKey) {
            Log::warning("API key or user not found");
            abort(401, 'API key or user not found');
        }

        $userApiKey = ApiKey::where('key_user', $apiUser)->first();

        if (!$userApiKey) {
            Log::warning("User not found: $apiUser");
            abort(401, 'User not found');
        }

        $valid = $userApiKey->key === $apiKey;

        Log::info("API key valid: " . ($valid ? 'Yes' : 'No'));

        if (!$valid) {
            Log::warning("Unauthorized API key for user: $apiUser");
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized API key');
        }

        return $apiUser;
    }); 

